# upload image with vich bundle symfony 2

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I'm trying to upload an image with VichUploaderBundle but I have this error on form submit:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   PiCrowdRise\WebBundle\Entity\Probleme::setImageFile() must be an
>   instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File, string given,
>   called in
>   E:\wamp\www\PI\PI\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php
>   on line 410 and defined

[My entity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtHi1.png)

[Setters and getters screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si2FN.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please add your code directly in the question, not in image format.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've forgot to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` tag? if not please add your full code (twig, formType, entity).